# Finding the hypervolume of a hypersphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question asked was: Find the volume of the hypersphere of equation x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=a^2 using integration . I found the volume to be (1/2)(π^2)(a^4) using spherical coordinates but I need to also use rectangular coordinates to verify the two are the same. I'm just very lost with all of the trig sub going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 
$$ \int_{-a}^a \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{a^2 - x^2-y^2-z^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}} ~ 1 ~ dw ~ dz ~ dy ~ dx $$

Comment: I used that integral, but I halved each on so it goes from zero to the positive limit and I multiplied the whole thing by 16.

Comment: You agree that? 
$$ V = \int_{-a}^a \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}} 2\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}~ dz ~ dy ~ dx $$
Now use spherical coordinates, $0\leq \rho \leq a$, $0\leq \varphi \leq \pi$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, and replace the function side the integral by $2\sqrt{a^2-\rho^2}$. Try doing that.